# create another dataframe datetime column based on the value of the datetime in another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has a datetime column lets call it my_dates.

I also have a list of dates which has say 5 dates for this example.

```
15th Jan 2020
20th Mar 2020
28th Jun 2020
20th Jul 2020
8th Aug 2020
```

What I want to do is create another column in my datframe where it looks at the datetime in my_dates column & where it is less than a date in my date list for it to take that value.

For example lets say for this example say its 23rd June 2020. I want the new column to have the value for this row of 28th June 2020. Hopefully the examples below are clear.

```
 More examples

 my_dates             expected_values

 14th Jan 2020        15th Jan 2020
 15th Jan 2020        15th Jan 2020
 16th Jan 2020        20th Mar 2020
 ...                  ...
 19th Mar 2020        20th Mar 2020
 20th Mar 2020        20th Mar 2020
 21st Mar 2020        28th Jun 2020
```

What is the most efficient way to do this rather than looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need `pd.merge_asof` with the argument `direction` set to `forward`

```
dates = ['15th Jan 2020',
'20th Mar 2020',
'28th Jun 2020',
'20th Jul 2020',
'8th Aug 2020'   ]

dates_proper = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates]

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('14-01-2020','21-03-2020'),columns=['my_dates'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dates_proper,columns=['date_list'])
```

---

```
merged_df = pd.merge_asof(
    df, df1, left_on=["my_dates"], right_on=["date_list"], direction="forward"
)

print(merged_df)

     my_dates  date_list
0  2020-01-14 2020-01-15
1  2020-01-15 2020-01-15
2  2020-01-16 2020-03-20
3  2020-01-17 2020-03-20
4  2020-01-18 2020-03-20
..        ...        ...
63 2020-03-17 2020-03-20
64 2020-03-18 2020-03-20
65 2020-03-19 2020-03-20
66 2020-03-20 2020-03-20
67 2020-03-21 2020-06-28
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally a usecase for `pd.merge_asof`! :) From the documentation

> Perform an asof merge. This is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key rather than equal keys.

It would have been helpful to make your example reproducible like this:

```
In [12]: reference = pd.DataFrame([['15th Jan 2020'],['20th Mar 2020'],['28th Jun 2020'],['20th Jul 2020'],['8th Aug 2020']], columns=['reference']).astype('datetime64')  
In [13]: my_dates = pd.DataFrame([['14th Jan 2020'], ['15th Jan 2020'], ['16th Jan 2020'], ['19th Mar 2020'], ['20th Mar 2020'],['21th Mar 2020']], columns=['dates']).astype('datetime64')
```

```
In [15]: pd.merge_asof(my_dates, reference, left_on='dates', right_on='reference', direction='forward')                                                                                                            
Out[15]: 
       dates  reference
0 2020-01-14 2020-01-15
1 2020-01-15 2020-01-15
2 2020-01-16 2020-03-20
3 2020-03-19 2020-03-20
4 2020-03-20 2020-03-20
5 2020-03-21 2020-06-28
```